# Purpose of String.Concat(Object) instead of String.Concat(String)

Tags: c#, .net, string, clr, boxing

What is the purpose of using `String.Concat(Object)` instead of `String.Concat(String)` in C#? Why just not use an implicit call of `Object.ToString()` instead of passing an `object` itself that may also cause boxing to happen?

```
Int32 i = 5;
String s = "i = ";

// Boxing happens, ToString() is called inside
Console.WriteLine(s + i);
// Why compiler doesn't call ToString() implicitly?
Console.WriteLine(s + i.ToString());
```

Gives us the following IL.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  MyDemo() cil managed
{
    // Code size       47 (0x2f)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init ([0] int32 i, [1] string s)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002:  stloc.0
    IL_0003:  ldstr      "i = "
    IL_0008:  stloc.1
    IL_0009:  ldloc.1
    IL_000a:  ldloc.0
    IL_000b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0010:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object)
    IL_0015:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_001a:  nop
    IL_001b:  ldloc.1
    IL_001c:  ldloca.s   i
    IL_001e:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
    IL_0023:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string)
    IL_0028:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_002d:  nop
    IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Program::MyDemo
```

Comment: Good question. I'd add here: why there's no `string Concat<T>(string s, T value)` method, which will be used by `+` operator.

Comment: @Dennis what would be the use of that?

Comment: @Dennis How would the compiler concatenate `T value` with `string s`? Can any `T` be concatenated at all?

Comment: It will be enough to call `return string.Concat(s, value.ToString());` inside. For value types this will avoid boxing.

Answer (score 3):

Why should the compiler do that? It can't.

If you pass in an object (in this case a boxed `int`), the only possibility for the compiler is to call `string.Concat(object, object)`. It can't call `string.Concat(string, string)` since not both of the parameters are a `string` and thus complies to the second overload.

Instead, it calls `string.Concat(object, object)` and does a `ToString` inside if applicable.

You as a developer have intimate knowledge of how the `string.Concat` method works. The compiler doesn't know that eventually it all becomes a `string`.

Also, what would happen if one of the `object`s is `null`? The `ToString` will fail with an exception. This doesn't make sense. Just pass in the `object` and let the code handle it.

Comment: Compiler does know that all the types inherit Object ultimately. Object contains ToString() method. Thus when compiler meets not a String argument of a function expecting String it may implicitly call ToString().

Comment: But you as a developer have intimate knowledge of how the `string.Concat` method works. The compiler doesn't know that eventually it all becomes a `string`.

Comment: @JohnDoe - where's the dividing line? Are you saying that, for *any* set of overloads where two overloads exist, where one accepts a `string` parameter in the same position that the other accepts an `object` parameter, it should always call `ToString()` on the object, and thus the `object` overload is never callable?

Comment: Indeed. This may apply for this specific method (and some more), but 99% of the methods it doesn't apply.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm just interested why Object overload ever exists since any Object can be ToString'ed. If an Object is uninitialized (NULL) there is probably a problem with code (using uninitialized variables), thus an Object overload 1) hides an error from a programmer emitting an empty string; 2) causes unneeded boxing degrading the performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Source:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c

Reveals that:

```
    public static String Concat(Object arg0) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        if (arg0 == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return arg0.ToString();
    }
```

It just simply creates a string representation of that object. So any object that you pass is converted into `String`. `String.Empty` if it is null. I think this also saves us from checking the "null" object before converting it to `string`.

Comment: Quite interesting that there is a method to concat _a single thing_.